# Is there a Unix Find command generation web page

Tags: unix, find, arguments, webpage

I use to refer to a web page that use to generate unix find command line options based on option that I select in the form. Unfortunately I lost the book mark and not able to recollect it. 
Does any body know about it , or has bookmarked it?

Prashant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://find.unixpin.com/

Found that via: http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/find.shtml